# Add opencv to an already existing project

Tags: android, opencv

Most resources that tell you how to install OpenCV for Android seem to assume that you are starting from scratch. (see: http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/dev_with_OCV_on_Android.html) I have a project that I have been working on for the last couple of weeks. Now I want to add OpenCv libraries. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the tutorial you linked has everything you need.
Read through Hello OpenCV Sample part, but start from step 5.

5 . Import OpenCV library to the current workspace and build it.

6 . Add it as library in the project properties of YOUR project.

Then import packages in your MainActivity as necessary, make sure to add permissions and features in the manifest if you want to use camera. 
And most importantly, add OpenCV library initialization in you MainActivity. Just as the tutorial describes.

Update your question if you run into any particular problems.
Hope that helps!