# Include the project tango SDK in an already existing project

Tags: android, android-ndk, google-project-tango

I am new to Android development and I have no idea how to include the library that comes with the Google Tango SDK.

The app, as it is, is a small java wrapper around a c++ core that is basically a lightweight render engine. It can render one model and handle input. It is all done in C++ using Android NDK.

The problem is that I now want to use functions like `onXyzIjAvailable()`. How do I include and use the library? I know of [this](https://developers.google.com/project-tango/apis/c/c-depth-perception), but I need to include the library and get  access to the `TangoService_connectOnXYZijAvailable()` function.

I want to stress that I am new to android development and I have never included anything. I have only written the code myself or used Android Studio to download and include the SDKs, generate the GRADLE files and take care of the compilation/makefles. I found [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19372034/add-opencv-to-an-already-existing-project) talking about adding a library, but I did not understand the answer. How do I import it to this project and build it?

Thank you so much for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You must download the current tango api and service sdk for C [here](https://developers.google.com/project-tango/downloads)
2. Unzip and place the folders (I named them tango_client_api and tango_service_sdk) you want to. I prefer a structure like that:

   - ProjectFolder/app/
   - ProjectFolder/build/...
   - ...
   - tango_client_api/
   - tango_service_sdk/
   - third-party/...
   - ...
3. Now you have to include the lib paths into your Android.mk makefile (located in path like ProjectFolder/app/src/main/jni/Android.mk) as followed:

   ```
   LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
   PROJECT_ROOT_FROM_JNI:= ../../../../..
   PROJECT_ROOT:= $(call my-dir)/../../../../..
   include $(CLEAR_VARS)

   LOCAL_MODULE    := lib_your_project_name
   LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := tango_client_api
   LOCAL_CFLAGS    := -std=c++11

   LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(PROJECT_ROOT)/tango_service_sdk/include/ \

   LOCAL_SRC_FILES := your-project-file1.cc \
                      your-project-file2.cc \
                      your-project-file3.cc

   LOCAL_LDLIBS    := -llog -lGLESv2 -L$(SYSROOT)/usr/lib
   include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
   $(call import-add-path, $(PROJECT_ROOT))
   $(call import-module,tango_client_api)
   ```
4. In your .h files you can use for example: `#include <tango_client_api.h>`
   to get access to all TangoService_functions

And that's it. I really recommend you to look into the tango C examples on github https://github.com/googlesamples/tango-examples-c

Comment: The project I am working on does nto have the makefiles. It only uses gradle. The gradle file can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/SZuRbNS7). I managed to add the folders and load the header files, but now I get linker errors since I have not added the .so files.
`Error:(110) undefined reference to 'TangoService_connectOnXYZijAvailable'`

Comment: Hi, usually you need will need a shared object to compile the source, but that means you will need to bundle the library into the apk. That's not what we do in most of the Tango application, because we want the application always dynamically linking to the library under system/lib. To achieve that, we put a .a file in our compile source folder, and compile against that. More detail is in .mk file of the tango example c example's here: https://github.com/googlesamples/tango-examples-c/blob/master/tango_client_api/Android.mk